# Creating a block within a theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I am trying go create a custom Magento 2 theme. Within this theme I want to add a custom block to the default `header.container`. This is what I have so far:

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/templates.header.phtml*

```
<p>Custom Header Content</p>
```

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="vendor.theme.header" template="Vendor_Theme::header.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/registration.php*

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Vendor/Theme',
    __DIR__
);
```

However, in the front end I get the following error message:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Vendor_Theme::header.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'vendor.theme.header'
```

Whenever I search how to create custom blocks within Magento I always come across module implementations, i.e. within *app/code/Vendor/Module/…*.

Since the error message says

```
in module: ''
```

I am now beginning to wonder if you aren't really supposed to define blocks within a theme at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `templates` directory from `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/` directory.

Then, change the template path to `Magento_Theme::header.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="header.container">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="vendor.theme.header" template="Magento_Theme::header.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body> 
</page>
```

Comment: Ah I see. So my theme never "owns" any templates directly, they are always in the appropriate module (like Magento_Theme)?

Comment: Yes. Please do upvote/accept as answer if this answers your question. It might help others too :)

Comment: Btw. I found out that it also works if I use `template="header.phtml"` and put the `header.phtml` in the `templates` folder within `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme`.

Comment: Great. But this approach helps us to organize the templates in the respective modules